# How to correct "Unable to open dependencies file" error on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, carthage

Working on an iOS app that has run on both simulators and devices as I developed it. Developing on an Intel iMac. Today Xcode asked me if I wanted to Update build settings - I clicked on the option to update.

Now, when trying to run on a simulator, I get this error message on a compile for simulators:

```
unable to open dependencies file (/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VTSwiftUI-dasdyffasovubcczkfgpeivfdkrn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VTSwiftUI.build/Release-iphonesimulator/<appName>.build/DerivedSources/.d)
```

(I've masked the username and app name in the code block above. All else reflects the exact error message.)

Because I'm using Carthage to include the FMDB framework I have different targets for running on a device and running on a simulator. The app compiles and runs on a device, but a simulator compile gives me the above error message after a compile.

It appears that it's looking for a file in the DerivedData folder named ".d" There is, of course, no such file in the DerivedData folder.

Other than trying to research the error code, with no success, I haven't tried anything because I'm not an expert on the innards of Xcode and have no idea what is causing this error or where to start trouble-shooting. I have cleaned the Build Folder multiple times.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you delete DerivedData?

Comment: Multiple times, with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stop this error.

Carthage requires a run script to handle fat binaries with a simulator slice (for details, see the Carthage Github site). In the dialog to add a run script is an option "Use discovered dependency file" that is checked by default and has a path to the dependency file. Unchecking this caused the error to go away.

I don't know why this behavior has changed or whether that option has been checked in the past (I believe it was), but now all works as advertised, and that's that counts.